# In which scripture (if any) is Krishna called "ranchor"?

Tags: krishna, name

This is in Hindi and not Sanskrit - and so the source is unlikely to be Puranic.  Is this only folklore?

This question is asking for a scripture that uses the word "ranchor".

Comment: The reason, scriptural reason all are added in the linked question

Comment: "scriptural reason" is dishonest.  I want a scripture that uses the word "ranchor"

Comment: Some Hindi names, Tamil names etc., are formed due to an incident from Sanskrit scriptures. There will be no mention of Rannchod in scripture directly but the cat of leaving battle is there. The name means who left the battle. It is due to a reason and leela. Still a duplicate.

Comment: "There will be no mention of Rannchod in scripture directly" you did this research in one minute?  It is not a sanskrit word, so it won't be in Sanskrit scripture.  Is it your contention that all Hindu scripture is in Sanskrit?